# Why apache binaries built with gcc 64-bits are mixed 32 and 64 bits?

Tags: compiling, solaris, gcc

On Solaris 10 I built gcc 4.9.0 for 64 bit. At least I thought I did. I'm building an Apache based stack, and other prerequisite tools.

If I build apache `file` shows a 64bit httpd:

```
file apache-test/bin/httpd 
apache-test/bin/httpd:        ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
```

So this suggests to me that my GCC is 64bit, but in the directory where I build my binaries I run `for f in *; do file $f; done` to run file against the whole directory I get:

```
for f in *; do file $f; done 
a.out:          empty file 
addr2line:      ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
ar:             ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
as:             ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
c_rehash:       executable /usr/bin/perl script 
c++:            ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
c++filt:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
compile_et:     executable shell script 
cpp:            ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
elfedit:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3], dynamically linked, not stripped
g++:            ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
gcc:            ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
gcc-ar:         ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3], dynamically linked, not stripped
gcc-nm:         ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3], dynamically linked, not stripped
gcc-ranlib:     ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3], dynamically linked, not stripped
gcov:           ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS POPC], dynamically linked, not stripped
gprof:          ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
gss-client:     ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
k5srvutil:      executable shell script 
kadmin:         ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
kdestroy:       ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
kinit:          ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
klist:          ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
kpasswd:        ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
krb5-config:    executable shell script 
kswitch:        ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
ktutil:         ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
kvno:           ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
ld:             ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
ld.bfd:         ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
nm:             ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
objcopy:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
objdump:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
openssl:        ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, UltraSPARC1 Extensions Required, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
pcre-config:    executable shell script 
pcregrep:       ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required, dynamically linked, not stripped
pcretest:       ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required, dynamically linked, not stripped
ranlib:         ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
readelf:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
sclient:        ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
sim_client:     ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
size:           ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
sparc-sun-solaris2.10-c++:      ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++:      ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
sparc-sun-solaris2.10-gcc:      ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
sparc-sun-solaris2.10-gcc-4.9.0:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 FMAF VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
sparc-sun-solaris2.10-gcc-ar:   ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3], dynamically linked, not stripped
sparc-sun-solaris2.10-gcc-nm:   ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3], dynamically linked, not stripped
sparc-sun-solaris2.10-gcc-ranlib:       ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3], dynamically linked, not stripped
strings:        ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
strip:          ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, UltraSPARC3 Extensions Required [CBCOND VIS3 VIS], dynamically linked, not stripped
uuclient:       ELF 64-bit MSB executable SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
```

Why am I seeing so many 32bit builds? If I've used gcc to build apache how can it be 64 bit when the gcc files are showing 32bit?

Answer (score 4):

GCC on Solaris has some defaults that are different, for example, than GCC on Linux.

For compiling 64 binaries you have to add

```
-m64
```

to your compile and link lines.

This makes GCC compatible to the Solaris Studio C compiler, in that respect.

On SPARC, compiling programs as 32 bit does not have as much disadvantages as on e.g. x86, where 64 Bit also gives you additional registers.

Comment: Thanks, my question was why are the gcc files in the bin directory showing as 32bit, if I've used them to build 64bit apache?

Comment: A 32- bit compiler program may generate 32-bit or 64-bit binaries; similarly for a 64-bit compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of a compiler as a function which generates output from some input, or

```
output_program = compile_function(input_source, args)
```

The exsistence of `compile_function` as a 32 or 64 bit binary affects *how* it does its job but not the output.

If we grossly simplify the role of 64-bit to simply increasing the amount of addressable memory, then technically a 32-bit compiler should only be problematic for situations where more than 4GB of addressable memory is requires to produce the output. Such a situation for current times, is mostly inconceivable (although I'm sure some people can come up with a contrived example that does exactly that).

Comment: Actually, when GCC switched to the TreeSSA internal representation and at the same time added whole program optimizations, it used to run out of memory somewhat regularly, until a simple garbage collector was added to GCC. Also, the Stalin compiler for Scheme is known for two things: producing code that can perform comparably to hand-optimized C, and using *ridiculous* amounts of memory and time to do so.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the enlightening comment. The main purpose of the second paragraph waffle was to illustrate that in all but a few cases it should not matter, although maybe I have underestimated "all but a few cases". Is there a way I can make this point better?